# Delete multiple selected Rows through radio button

Tags: excel, vba

the code I have prompt a popup requesting which row to delete, unfortunately when I press escape or cancel, whichever cell is active on the worksheet ends up getting deleted.

What I am looking for is a function where if I press escape on the keyboard or 'x' on the popup window it does not delete the row

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub DeleteRow()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim iRowCount As Integer
    Dim iForCount As Integer

    On Error Resume Next

    Set selectedRng = Application.Selection
    Set selectedRng = Application.InputBox("Range", , selectedRng.Address, Type:=8)

    iRowCount = selectedRng.Rows.Count
    For iForCount = iRowCount To 1 Step -1
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(selectedRng.Rows(iForCount)) = 0 Then
    selectedRng.Rows(iForCount).EntireRow.Delete
    selectedRnd.Rows(iForCount).Delete
    End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next`. This line hides **all** error messages but the errors still occur, you just cannot see them. So remove that line and fix your errors. This might be of interest: [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)

Answer (score 0):

The InputBox function returns a string, so using SET to assign the result to your selectedRng variable (which has not been declared, so will be considered a variant) will simply be skipped when the user cancels the input box.  Therefore the variable will continue to hold the Application.Selection, which you assigned to it in the preceding line.

The input box returns "False" if the user click cancel or "X" or hits Escape.

I would try declaring a string variable to capture the result of the input, as in

```
dim strResult as string

strResult = Application.InputBox("Range", , selectedRng.Address)
if strResult <> "False" then
   set selectedRng = Range(strResult)
  'delete the rows now...
end if
```

Comment: When debugging, I would also consider removing the line "On Error Resume Next" line, and stepping through your code to see exactly where it breaks.

Comment: Thanks Steve, as I am still learning VBA, are you able to provide how the aforementioned can be integrated in the macro I have?  Much appreciated :)

Comment: If you remove or comment out the "on error resume next" line, then the macro will stop when an error is encountered, and highlight the offending line of code.  (NOTE: there is a setting in VBA to control this behaviour.  In the IDE, Tools menu > Options > General Tab > Error Trapping area: set this to "Break on Unhandled Errors" ) This is extremely helpful when troubleshooting.  Instead of your function just not working, you can see the actual line of code that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys,

I decided to completely simplify the code and it works fine now

```
Sub DeleteRow()
 Dim Rng As Range, Num As String
On Error Resume Next
Set Rng = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please Select Start Row ", Title:="Delete Rows", Type:=8)
    If Split(Rng.Address, "$")(2) < 1 Then
        'MsgBox "Please choose a Number Greater than 1"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Num = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please Insert Number of Rows", Title:="Delete Rows", Type:=1)
        If Num = False Then Exit Sub
             Rng.Resize(Num).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```